# general recursion in scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I am having a bit of problems with recursion. Just want to make sure I get better. Let's say I want to see if a n number is in a list. If it is, it returns true, otherwise, false.

```
(define (contains? n lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) false]
    [(cons? lst)
   .....  (first lst)
      (contains? (rest lst)
```

the recursion part always tricks me. Is it necessary to call `cons?` here?  Because if you are just looking for the first of a list, it isn.t

```
(define (contains? n lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) false]
   [(= n (first lst)) true]))

(check-expect (contains? 1 (list 1 2)) true)
(check-expect (contains? 1 empty) false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to use `cons?` in the case of a list of numbers (or in general: a list of atoms): either the list is empty or is non-empty. You'd only use `cons?` to check if the parameter is not a list, but in general you don't have to validate this: if it isn't a list, then the function fails (as it should).

A wholly different matter happens when you have a list of lists: in that case we have to use `cons?` (or equvalently: `pair?`) to test if the first element is a list itself, and also advance the recursion over it. But for the current example, what you *do* have to consider, is in these three cases:

```
(define (contains? n lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) false]              ; the list is empty
    [(= (first lst) n) true]          ; current element is the one we're looking for
    [else (contains? n (rest lst))])) ; current element is not the one, keep looking
```

Comment: i get it now. but why wont the else part work? Keeps telling me it expects two arguments, but found 1.

Comment: nevermind. you forgot the n after contains?. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Why do you use `first` and `rest`? In Scheme they don't exist and in #!racket they aren't the same as `car` and `cdr`.

Comment: @Sylwester I have reasons to believe that OP is using idiomatic Racket as his learning language. Why? because once I wrote an answer with `car` and `cdr` and he didn't know about them! so I'm using `first` and `rest`. Also, the question is tagged as `racket`. In general I try to adapt my solution to use a similar style/conventions as the code in the question

Comment: You were more restrained than I would have been -- I'd have wanted to rewrite it using `match`. ;) Seriously, that would be _so_ much cleaner to write and read. But yes, I recognize the value in people learning to do it the tedious way, first.